# Pass action as Parameter on Command Prompt (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a program in linux bash and following are ways to start/stop that program:

```
start_program
stop_program
restart_program.
```

I have copied above scripts in /usr/bin so these scripts are working as command. but I want that instead of above commands I just type program name then pass action as parameter. for example if i want to start program then i should write on command prompt:

```
ProgramName start
```

if i want to uninstall then

```
ProgramName uninstall
```

if restart

```
ProgramName restart
```

so how can i make it that i just write Program name then pass action as parameter and Press enter to do that thing.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking. Do you want to know how to process parameters passed to a shell script & act on them inside a single script?

Comment: So far I have used [read -ep "Enter Option" $Option: ]. but i get it after executing my program. but in above scenario, I'm passing "Option" at same time when I am executing program. so this is the thing that I dont know how to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A common approach is to use a case statement:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
    # Your Start Code
    ;;
  stop)
    # Your Stop Code
    ;;
  restart)
    # Your Restart Code
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

If your `restart` is just `stop` then `start`, you can do:

```
start() {
  # Your Start Code
}

stop() {
  # Your Stop Code
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: I think thats the thing what I'm looking for. let me implement it and then get back to you if i get any issue. thanks.

Comment: In my code , for restart case, i called stop program and then start program. Now how can i manage it in above case?

Comment: The easiest way would be to put the start code and stop code in functions. I will add an example to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Sionide21 has it right.

There is a great little write up on this over here:

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to a case statement.

Start/Stop/restart/uninstall your program with an Argument **using if statement** in bash/shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

start_module() {
      # Your start Code
}

stop_module() {
      # Your stop Code
}

restart_module() {
      # Your restart Code
}

uninstall_module() {
      # Your uninstall Code
}


if [ $# != 1 ]; then                # If Argument is not exactly one
    echo "Some message"
    exit 1                         # Exit the program
fi


ARGUMENT=$(echo "$1" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')     # Converts Argument in lower case. This is to make user Argument case independent. 

if   [[ $ARGUMENT == start ]]; then

    start_module

elif [[ $ARGUMENT == stop ]]; then

    stop_module

elif [[ $ARGUMENT == uninstall ]]; then

    uninstall_module

elif [[ $ARGUMENT == restart ]]; then

    restart_module

else 
    echo "Only one valid argument accepted: START | STOP | RESTART | UNINSTALL
          case doesn't matter. "
fi
```

Save this code into myScript.sh

```
Usage: 

./myScript.sh Start
./myScript.sh Stop
./myScript.sh check
./myScript.sh uninstall
```

Here is [an example of a real-world program](https://github.com/Raman-Kathpalia/IBM-MQ-Multi-Instance-QMgr-Automatic-Start/blob/master/MQ_Multi_Instance_Monitor.bash) that embodies this style of execution.

***Side-Note:*** Omitting any existing module/functionality or adding another can be done easily.

**How to take out/suppress a specific module from running (say for maintenance)?**

Taking out a specific module off ***if statement block*** will disable it since that module won't be called during runtime.